# How to overwrite a configuration file with Docker

Tags: docker

I have a Docker project with the following structure:

```
.
├── config
└── Dockerfile
```

where the `Dockerfile` is

```
FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 8118
RUN apk --update add privoxy
COPY config /etc/privoxy/config
CMD ["privoxy", "--no-daemon"]
```

and the `config` contains the two lines

```
listen-address 0.0.0.0:8118
forward-socks5 / tor:9050 .
```

In the container, I would like to make the Privoxy configuration file, of which the default location is `/etc/privoxy` (cf. https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html), into the 'local' `config` file, which is what I'm trying to achieve with the `COPY` directive.

However, if I `docker build --tag my_privoxy .` followed by `docker run my_privoxy`, I see the following error message:

```
2017-05-02 10:40:29.371 7f2ce5f00b48 Info: Privoxy version 3.0.24
2017-05-02 10:40:29.371 7f2ce5f00b48 Info: Program name: privoxy
2017-05-02 10:40:29.371 7f2ce5f00b48 Fatal error: can't check configuration file '//config':  Invalid argument
```

I don't see how the expected location of the configuration file ends up as `'//config'` in the container; the use of `COPY` seems to me consistent with https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy. What is wrong with the above `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 2):

is `/etc/privoxy/config` a directory? if no, then your command should be like

```
COPY config /etc/privoxy/
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `privoxy --help`, the command accepts a `[configfile]` optional input. So I changed the last line to

```
CMD ["privoxy", "--no-daemon", "/etc/privoxy/config"]
```

and it works. (I still don't understand why it doesn't work without the `configfile` input though, as `/etc/privoxy/config` should be the default).

Answer (score 0):

> In the container, I would like to make the Privoxy configuration file

You could mount a volume into the folder with the configuration you want. This would be done with `docker run -v hostFolder:containerFolder imagename`. This however will not result in a new image with the configuration instead you will get a container with the configuration you want.